# Regular expression to validate integration expression (calculus)

Tags: java, regex

I am developing a program in java which will find the integration of the given function. e.g cos(x+3x^2).Now i want to check whether user has given correct input..is there any regular expression which we can use while checking the validity of input? eg the input must always start with integration sign and end with dx.I want the regular expression which will cover cases like cos(cos(x+5)) etc

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use regular expressions for checking anything that needs counting: it is not powerful enough. It is theoretically impossible to use regular expressions for a simpler problem of validating if parentheses in a string are balanced.

You need to build a parser for your expressions. A simple top-down parser will do, or you could use a parser generator, such as ANTLR or JavaCC. You can also use one of the available [open source expression languages](http://java-source.net/open-source/expression-languages) for your project.